# btrfs RAID-1 size

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid-1, btrfs

I have a btrfs raid1 filesystem with a couple of disks

<kbd>1TB</kbd>
<kbd>2TB</kbd>
<kbd>2TB</kbd>
<kbd>2TB</kbd>
<kbd>5TB</kbd>

which should result in a total of a <kbd>6TB</kbd> RAID-1 array.

The result of the 
http://carfax.org.uk/btrfs-usage/

> Total space for files: 6000 Unusable: 0
>
> The results shown here do not take into account the space used by
>   metadata, nor any additional unusable space caused by btrfs's block
>   reservations, which are necessary for CoW operation.

---

```
Label: 'foo'  uuid: ....
    Total devices 5 FS bytes used 1.55TiB
    devid    1 size 1.82TiB used 449.00GiB path /dev/sdc
    devid    2 size 1.82TiB used 448.03GiB path /dev/sdf
    devid    3 size 931.51GiB used 0.00B path /dev/sda
    devid    4 size 1.82TiB used 694.00GiB path /dev/sdb
    devid    5 size 4.55TiB used 1.55TiB path /dev/sdd

btrfs-progs v4.2.2
```

---

```
btrfs filesystem df /mnt                              1 
Data, RAID1: total=1.55TiB, used=1.54TiB
System, RAID1: total=32.00MiB, used=256.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=7.00GiB, used=2.29GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

Where it says that it is almost full?!?

---

**Why do I only see 1.55TiB when there should be (close to) 6TB?**

Yes, I do get the ENOMEM errors!

Yes, I tried to rebalance already, no change.
(`btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt`)

**On the other hand side, nautilus reports 6TB total size and 2.8TB free!?!**

Comment: Can you add the output of 'btrfs fi us -T /mnt'? Have you tried to run 'btrfs fi re max /mnt'